# detect currently executing browser and tab/window

Tags: c#, winforms

I know how to detect already running browsers. Now, I want to know how to detect browser that is currently executing and I also want to know how to detect if new tab/window opens of some browser in c# winforms.

e-g

if user click on x browser; my program should tell x browser is running. now if user opens a new tab in that browser then my program should tell "tab opening in x browser".

I did research but could not find exact!
Thanks

Comment: If you're wanting to work with, say, the current foreground window, and wanting to detect UI changes, then you should probably be going down the [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327(v=vs.110).aspx) route.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do that, both of them use [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as there is no managed code for such thing :

1. Polling :
   You program should call [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) periodically then [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and test if the open focused Window is a browser or not and that's also the active tab title (page title).
2. Event listening :
   You should [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on a system-level event : EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND to detect the new focused window. You can then SetWinEventHook on an object-level EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE or EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE for every browser's window to detect tab changes.

Tips :

> - The client thread that calls SetWinEventHook must have a message loop in order to receive events.
> - For out-of-context events, the event is delivered on the same thread that called SetWinEventHook.
> - When you use SetWinEventHook to set a callback in managed code, [you should explicitly tell] the garbage collector not to move the callback.
> - While a hook function processes an event, additional events may be triggered, which may cause the hook function to reenter before the processing for the original event is finished. The problem with reentrancy in hook functions is that events are completed out of sequence unless the hook function handles this situation. For more information, see [Guarding Against Reentrancy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318100%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: In another question you commented with _`EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE` occur a lot, it is triggered even when you move the mouse on the same tab of the same window !_ . Did you find a solution for it?